# RXTX how to reading from com port

Tags: java, rxtx

Hi i have somthing like this

```
package compot;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import gnu.io.*;


public class core {

    private static SerialPort p;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println("start");
        while(ports.hasMoreElements())
        {
            CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            System.out.print(port.getName() + " -> " + port.getCurrentOwner() + " -> ");
            switch(port.getPortType())
            {
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                    System.out.println("parell");
                break;
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                    //System.out.println("serial");
                try {
                    p = (SerialPort) port.open("core", 1000);
                    int baudRate = 57600; // 57600bps
                    p.setSerialPortParams(
                            baudRate,
                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("stop");
    }
}
```

But I dont know how to read from port ?? I have read [this tutorial](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/how-to-open-serial-port-using-rxtx/) but i dont know what "Demo application" they mean ??

**EDIT**

```
OutputStream outStream = p.getOutputStream();
                    InputStream inStream = p.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inStream));
                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                        System.out.println(inputLine);
                    in.close();
```

I have add this code but i recive

> Stable Library
>   ========================================= Native lib Version =
>   RXTX-2.1-7 Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7 start /dev/ttyUSB3 -> null
>   -> Underlying input stream returned zero bytes stop

Comment: Any follow up coming? No reaction at all? :p

Comment: This could be a problem with the flow control. you can set this on the port with port.setFlowControl() method. However, it is impossible for me to tell which flow control you should use. Maybe start reading things about serial ports in general: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-4.html And I would suggest reading the inputstream byte-wise not line-wise. But this depends on the device you're actually trying to communicate with.

Comment: Im using TTL to RS232 converter, but wht im getting ttyUSB0 not ttyS0 ?? But when i insert pendrive it doesnt see it

Answer (score 7):

Is this your code? What are you actually trying to do there? :p

In order to read from a SerialPort, you need to declare this port:

```
CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/tty/USB0"); //on unix based system
```

Then open a connection on this port:

```
SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("NameOfConnection-whatever", 0);
```

Next step would be to set the params of this port (if needed):

```
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(38400, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
```

This is my config - your's might differ accordingly :)

Now you're ready to read some data on this port!
To get the data, you need to get the serialPorts inputstream and read from that:

```
InputStream inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
while (active) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[22];
            while ((buffer[0] = (byte) inputStream.read()) != 'R') {
            }
            int i = 1;
            while (i < 22) {
                if (!active) {
                    break;
                }
                buffer[i++] = (byte) inputStream.read();
            }
            //do with the buffer whatever you want!
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
}
```

What I'm actually doing here is reading from the inputstream using it's `read()` method. This will block until data is available or return -1 if end of stream is reached. In this example I wait until I get an 'R' character and then read the next 22 bytes into a buffer. And that's how you read data.

1. Get the serialPorts inputstream
2. use .read() method
3. have that all inside a loop and exit loop when canceled (in my case, the `active` can be set to false by another method and thus end the reading process.

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
if (socketReader.ready()) {
}
```

so that the socket responds only when there is something to read in the Buffer Stream 
so the Exception never Occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your try block:

```
OutputStream outStream = p.getOutputStream();
InputStream inStream = p.getInputStream();
```

Comment: So what is `p = (SerialPort) port.open("core", 1000);` this for, this first part "core" need for ??

Comment: the serialport connection is named "core" and timeouts after 1000ms when the current owner does not release the connection within that time.. you probably should have no process using this port anyways

Comment: This name will identify the owner of the port. Just use your application name. More info: [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html)